# Averaging select values from a list box. C#

Tags: c#

Before I ask my question, let me explain my project.

My program is designed to read a .txt file and separate that data into two different list boxes. The text file would read as the following for tag number followed by travel distance (however there is around 100 lines of information):

W980

8.60

F840

9.56

W482

3.50

D487

8.74

F400

4.01

D120

0.90

The data from the .txt file is then broken up into two strings such that the first line here (W980) will appear in the list box named lstboxTag and the second line (8.60) will appear in the list box named lstboxTravel.

When comparing the list box side by side, the tag and the travel distance will match up. However, I need to find the averages of each tag group (D, F, and W) and to count how many tags we have of each group while only using the information from the now filled list boxes.

Without using an array or list, how is this possible?

Comment: First, what have you tried?  Second... what do you have against tiny arrays and lists?  100 lines of data is 50 actual sets of data.  Reading into a proper data structure will help you with the problem, so why object to them?

Comment: I am not allowed to use an arrays or list for this project. I really have not tried anything because I have no idea how to get started. I am guessing I need to take the string and see if it contains the letter "D," "F," or "W."

Comment: So this is a homework problem set by a teacher who is forcing you to use unrealistic, bad programming practices that are going to make you a worse programmer?  Gotta love those.

Answer (score 0):

Since we're working with unrealistic restrictions and not much information, here's an unrealistic answer:

```
textBox1.Text=string.Join("\r\n",Enumerable.Range(0,Math.Min(listBox1.Items.Count,listBox2.Items.Count)).Select(i=>new{tag=listBox1.Items[i].ToString(),value=double.Parse(listBox2.Items[i].ToString())}).GroupBy(row=>row.tag.Substring(0,1),r=>r.value).Select(grp=>string.Format("Group: {0}, Count: {1}, Average: {2}",grp.Key,grp.Count(),grp.Average())).OrderBy(g=>g));
```

Which, for the data you've given in your question, gives the following output:

```
Group: D, Count: 2, Average: 4.82
Group: F, Count: 2, Average: 6.785
Group: W, Count: 2, Average: 6.05
```

As to how it works...

First you stitch together the values from the two list boxes to give you the working data set, with appropriate type conversions.  Then you group the data that you want to aggregate across by a suitable key (the first character of the tag in this case) and perform the aggregations you need: Count and Average.  Finally convert the results to something readable.

Broken down it looks something like this:

```
textBox1.Text = 
    // this is the outer, final stage that converts the line collection to text
    string.Join("\r\n", 
        // start with a list of numbers, no more than the smallest item count
        // (for the supplied data this is [0..5])
        Enumerable.Range(0, Math.Min(listBox1.Items.Count, listBox2.Items.Count))
        // use those to index the Items collections on your listboxes
        .Select(i => new { tag = listBox1.Items[i].ToString(), value = double.Parse(listBox2.Items[i].ToString()) })
        // group the values by the tag character
        .GroupBy(row => row.tag.Substring(0,1), r => r.value)
        // aggregate and produce a line for each group
        .Select(grp => string.Format("Group: {0}, Count: {1}, Average: {2}", grp.Key, grp.Count(), grp.Average()))
        // sort output - this is optional and probably unnecessary
        .OrderBy(r=> r)
    );
```

Since your teacher (or whoever) set you a stupid unrealistic problem I'd be just the sort to submit a stupid and unrealistic answer.  Your mileage may vary.  I wouldn't advise using even the commented version though... unless your course has already focused heavily on LINQ that will probably just demonstrate to your teacher that you are doing your homework online.

And if this isn't actually homework, tell your boss that his insistence on storing data in list boxes, no matter how briefly, is not only inefficient and stupid but likely to cause errors in processing as well.

And I fully expect downvotes for this answer.  It's a bad answer :)